# Ghostscript should not embed font but only list a substitute

Tags: pdf, fonts, ghostscript

I do have a pdf generating pipeline where at the end ghostscript (Linux) gets called to end up with a PDF (input ps). The PDF must be as small as possible, so the general commandline used is

```
ps2pdf13 -dSAFER -dPDFSETTINGS=/default -dEmbedAllFonts=false -dNoOutputFonts -dFastWebView infile outfile
```

That generates nice PDF files without fonts included as wanted, the assumption is that the target system then should use whatever they have to replace. Yes, this can mean that different systems do use slightly different fonts and as such get different looks.

Mostly works, there are 7 different fonts listed in the PDFs properties. Works nicely on Linux.

Windows (Acrobat Reader) complains about one of them missing, and then doesn't render any of that ones characters.

I know I can let gs embed fonts, except that increases the PDF size by 50%. Would like to avoid that (while its around 6000bytes, this multiplies by approx 30000 times for every run, and as such does count).

I would love to have a way to "embed" in the PDF an information of "For Font Helvetica-Narrow just use Arial Narrow" (or similar).

Does that exist?

[Edit]

Sorry for the late reply, busy. :(

Well, ok. I was thinking of a list of possible options for font selection. Also, coming from that way, the question may be gone the wrong way.

The options, btw, do make different size, though it seems to be the
-dEmbedAllFonts one to be responsible for sizes, -dNoOutPutFonts
doesnt seem to have any effect actually.

I have to compare against a (very old) distiller, which we try to replace, and using pdffonts, I get the following tables:

psp2df:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
Helvetica-Narrow                     Type 1            Custom           no  no  no      11  0
Helvetica-Bold                       Type 1            Custom           no  no  no       9  0
Helvetica-Narrow-Bold                Type 1            WinAnsi          no  no  no      13  0
Courier                              Type 1            Custom           no  no  no      15  0
Courier-Bold                         Type 1            Standard         no  no  no      10  0
Helvetica                            Type 1            Custom           no  no  no       8  0
Times-Italic                         Type 1            Standard         no  no  no      21  0
```

distiller:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
Helvetica                            Type 1            Custom           no  no  no       4  0
Helvetica-Bold                       Type 1            Custom           no  no  no       5  0
Courier                              Type 1            Custom           no  no  no       6  0
Courier-Bold                         Type 1            Custom           no  no  no       7  0
Helvetica-Narrow                     Type 1            Custom           no  no  no       8  0
Helvetica-Narrow-Bold                Type 1            Custom           no  no  no       9  0
Times-Italic                         Type 1            Custom           no  no  no      15  0
```

With the ps2pdf created PDF file Acrobat Reader complains about "Font
Helvetica-Narrow can not be found". The distiller one works.
I don't get it. It's the same list, at least for that font.

And obviously it then looks crap.

One solution is to embed fonts. Then the font list turns into

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
XVQNWP+Helvetica-Narrow              Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no      11  0
Helvetica-Bold                       Type 1            Custom           no  no  no       9  0
LBTZEH+Helvetica-Narrow-Bold         Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no      13  0
Courier                              Type 1            Custom           no  no  no      15  0
Courier-Bold                         Type 1            Standard         no  no  no      10  0
Helvetica                            Type 1            Custom           no  no  no       8  0
Times-Italic                         Type 1            Standard         no  no  no      21  0
```

and the file size goes up a load, which we want to avoid. Distiller
shows its possible, but not how.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot define a substitute font for a missing one, that is entirely at the discretion of the viewer. How would it help anyway ? If the substitute you define isn't available to the viewer, then it would have to fall back to its own substitution anyway, or fail altogether.

A few comments on your command line:

If you are using `-dNoOutputFonts` then your PDF file should not contain **any** fonts, or font references, at all. It would also be (considerably) larger than disabling font embedding, and possibly larger than the same PDF with subset fonts embedded, because all the text will be included as path data, for even moderate amounts of text the repetition of the path data will exceed the font size.

Its hard to see how you are managing to produce a file which ends up referencing fonts, but doesn't include the font.

You don't need to specify `-dPDFSETTINGS=/default` because that is the default...

If you want a smaller file, do not specify `-dFastWebView` that produces a linearised PDF file which is larger (because of the format) than a non-linearised file. Very few viewers honour it, even those that do can only accelerate the first page view, and if the file is very small, its pointless since the entire file will arrive as fast as the early portion of the linearised file.

Forcing the version to 1.3 will likely make the file size larger too, at least in the future.